# SVG File is not visible after Port-Change to htpps

Tags: html, svg

I have changed my Port from "http" to "https" (added a SSL-Certificate). After that the Logo of my Website, which is a SVG file, is now not visible and instead the alt-text is shown.
The file still exist in the dictionary and in the file there are no link that could be effected by the change.

Any ideas how to fix that?

SVG File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="https://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="https://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="https://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="https://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="https://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="https://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="210mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 210"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg8"
   inkscape:version="1.0.1 (3bc2e813f5, 2020-09-07)"
   sodipodi:docname="Logo ohne text.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs2" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="653.37841"
     inkscape:cy="194.74847"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     inkscape:document-rotation="0"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1280"
     inkscape:window-height="961"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata5">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="https://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title />
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Ebene 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:none;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:#ffffff;stroke-width:10;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect10"
       width="200.00017"
       height="199.99991"
       x="5.0000038"
       y="4.9999933"
       ry="15.652162" />
    <text
       xml:space="preserve"
       style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:10.5833px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Calisto MT';-inkscape-font-specification:'Calisto MT, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;white-space:pre;inline-size:82.3788;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:0.264583;"
       x="48.643055"
       y="104.23512"
       id="text851"
       transform="matrix(12.580242,0,0,13.029993,-609.70959,-1207.3329)"><tspan
         x="48.643055"
         y="104.23512"><tspan
           style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:10.5833px;font-family:'Calisto MT';-inkscape-font-specification:'Calisto MT, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.264583">CK</tspan></tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

HTML Implementation:

```
<img src="path" style="width: 60px; height: 26px;">
```

Comment: please try using an absolute path

Comment: did not worked, same problem as before